# I have this code and I want to make it stop when a user enters q and prints what I want it to do. What do I do next?

Tags: python

I have this code and I want to make it stop when a user enters q and prints what I want it to do.
What do I do next?

```
sum=0
counter=0
while True:
    enter=int(input("Enter a number:"))
    counter=counter+1
    sum=sum+enter
    print(counter,sum)

if enter=='q':
    quit
print(Counter,sum)
```

Comment: add change `quit` to `exit()` I guess ... and probably do your check prior to trying to make it an int

Comment: Input a string, check that it isn't `q`, if not convert to int and continue

Comment: @JoranBeasley Using `quit` is not the best of ideas. To cite the [documentation of `quit` (and `exit`)](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/constants.html#quit): "They are useful for the interactive interpreter shell and should not be used in programs."

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your code to check `enter` for `'q'` before converting it to an `int`:

```
sum=0
counter=0
while True:
    enter=input("Enter a number:")
    if enter=='q':
        return
    try:
        enter = int(enter)
    except:
        continue
    counter=counter+1
    sum=sum+enter
    print(counter,sum)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the input upon each iteration to test for `q`.

```py
num_sum = 0
counter = 0

while True:
    enter = input('Enter a number: ')

    if enter == 'q':
        break
    if not enter.isdecimal():
        continue

    counter += 1
    num_sum += int(enter)
    print(counter, num_sum)

print(counter, num_sum)
```

Answer (score 0):

You must take into account that `sum` is a word that cannot be a variable because it has meaning in Python.

```
Sum=0
counter=0
while (enter:= (input("Enter a number:"))) != 'q':
    Sum += int(enter)
    counter +=1
    
print(Sum, counter)
```